# Replace newlines, but keep the blank lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, newline

I want to replace newlines (\r\n) with space, but I want to keep the blank lines. In other words, I want to replace \r\n with ' ', if \r\n is not preceded by another \r\n. For example:

```
line 1

line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Shold end up as...

```
line 1

line 2 line 3 line 4
```

But not as "line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4", which is what I'm doing right now with this

```
preg_replace("/\r\n/", " ", $string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)
```

Of course, you can change `\n` to whatever you need.

Working example: http://ideone.com/dF5L9

Comment: The only one suggested thus far that actually appears to work as required.  +1.

Comment: Beautiful. I used (?<!\r\n)\r\n(?!\r\n) and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 preg_replace("/(.)\r\n(?=.|$)/", "$1 ", $string);
```

Comment: Nope. It still kills the blank lines. Thanks for trying.

Comment: This reduces two new-lines to one, the first one, just after  `line 1`, can be matched by the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
preg_replace("/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/", " ", $string);
```