# How to remove newlines but keep blank ones in a text file?

Tags: python, string, text

My question is essentially identical to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258549/replace-newlines-but-keep-the-blank-lines), but I'd like to perform that operation using python 3. The text in my file looks something like this:

```
'''
Chapter One ~~ Introductory


The institution of a leisure class is found in its best development at
the higher stages of the barbarian culture; as, for instance, in feudal...
'''
```

Per numerous suggestions I've found, I have tried:

```
with open('veblen_txt_test.txt', 'r') as src:
    with open('write_new.txt', 'w') as dest:
       for line in src:
           if len(line) > 0:
               line = line.replace('\n', ' ') 
               dest.write(line)
           else:
               line = line + '\n\n'
               dest.write('%s' % (line))
```

But this returns:

```
'''
Chapter One ~~ Introductory  The institution of a leisure class is found in its best development at the higher stages of the barbarian culture; as, for instance, in feudal...
'''
```

The intended output is:

```
'''
Chapter One ~~ Introductory  


The institution of a leisure class is found in its best development at the higher stages of the barbarian culture; as, for instance, in feudal...
'''
```

I have tried using `rstrip()`:

```
with open('veblen_txt_test.txt', 'r') as src:
    with open('write_new.txt', 'w') as dest:
       for line in src:
           if len(line) > 0:
               line = line.rstrip('\n') 
               dest.write('%s%s' % (line, ' '))
           else:
               line = line + '\n\n'
               dest.write('%s' % (line))
```

But that yields the same result.

Most of the responses online address removing blank spaces, not keeping them; I have no doubt the solution is simple, but I've been trying different variations of the above code for about an hour and a half and just thought to ask the community. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Obviously, `len("\n") > 0`:) So you can slightly modify this condition to make your first try work

Comment: as an aside, instead of `dest.write('%s' % (line))` just do `dest.write(line)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we change the `len(line) > 0` to `len(line) > 1`, it does the job. This is because `\n` counts as 1 character. You'll also have to remove this line: `line = line + '\n\n'` as it adds 4 more extra lines (since there are two `\n` in between `Chapter One ~~ Introductory` and `The institution...`.

Output:

```
Chapter One ~~ Introductory 

The institution of a leisure class is found in its best development at the higher stages of the barbarian culture; as, for instance, in feudal...
```

Comment: `len('\n')` is `1`

Comment: I did not account for `len(\n) = 1` because I had run `print(len(line))` for every line of the original text and remember seeing the new lines were returning `len = 0`. There must've been some error when I wrote and interpreted that output, because I've repeated the exercise and it's consistent with what everyone has said here! Thank you all for your input!